# How to restrict the print output from a numpy array when computing an image wavelet?

Tags: python, printing, numpy

This code prints out an endless column of numbers from image wavelet to the console. I need to restrict the output to the first 50 or 100 items. I have tried to accomplish that, but could not get what I need.

```
  def waveletdbbiorone(self):     #function for Wavelets computation
          for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
             imgwbior = mahotas.imread (filename) #read the image
             arraywbior = numpy.array([imgwbior])#make an array 
             coefwbior = pywt.wavedec(arraywbior,'db1')#compute wavelet coefficients
             arr = numpy.array([coefwbior])
             np.set_printoptions(threshold=3)
             # print arr
             for elem in arr.flat:
              print('{}\t'.format(elem)) #, end ='')  #print out the result
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for i in range(min(50, len(arr.flat))):
    elem  = arr.flat[i]
    print('{}\t'.format(elem))
```

which can be shortened as:

```
for i in range(min(50, len(arr.flat))):
    print('{}\t'.format(arr.flat[i]))
```

***EDIT :***

Or, as suggested by `Jaime`, the much more pythonic:

```
for elem in arr.flat[:50]:
    print('{}\t'.format(elem))
```

Comment: I prefer something like `for elem in arr.flat[:50]:`